# Unable to click on the Submit button using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a submit button on my UI page but I am not able to click on that button even if I take the XPath of that. Below is the UI code for button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-sm-2" value="Submit">
```

but the XPath i am getting is

```
//*[@id="form"]/div[5]/input
```

So please provide me some inputs to select the button. I also need to scroll down the page a bit as the button is also not visible on the page.

Answer (score 1):

u may try by using cssSelector like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.col-sm-2"));
```

for this, class "btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.col-sm-2" must be unique.

if the element is not visible in the screen, than use like below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement elem =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.col-sm-2"));

 //this line will scroll down to make element visible
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," +(elem.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");
```

than click on that element:

```
elem.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for  the reply i treid but i am getting the following error [Element with cssSelector: .btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.col-sm-2 was found -----unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (467, 591). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: This worked for me! We were trying some automated browsing on coursera.com. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use this xpath it will work

```
//*[@id='form']/div[5]/input // if nodes are correct then
```

if yor page has got only on tag with attribute value value="Submit" then

```
//*[@value='Submit']
```

Comment: @ raj NishKumar  Can you just help me out with a page scroll down code as well i tried using java script 
    JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;   
    javascript.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,900)", "");                                                                         Its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try following xpath

//input[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg col-sm-2']

this should work